# Incomplete Wordpress export

Tags: wordpress, image, export

I have a problem with a huge wordpress website. I can't export data using the native Wordpress Export feature (too posts, the process simply gives an incomplete XML file), I've been able to export each single post_type (post, news, pages, custom post type, ecc.) but doing so I miss all the images. Basically I've learned that WP export all media infos, only when you do a complete export.

Since I have to deal with tens of thousands of posts, I can't open one by one and add the featured image, I need to, somehow, automate this procedure. (Basically I should be able to find the featured image url "scraping" the website creating a list of URLs from the XML file - I have access to admin setup, but as already stated, I can't retrieve such info one by one).

PREMISE: I can't access the DB nor install other plugins in WP, or change any php file.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this may be done during the import process. Have you seen the checkbox that looks similar to this?

[image]